# Is it possible to create an HTML button in a text box to convert content to PDF (offline, CKEditor)?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, pdf-generation

So, my platform is integrated with **CKEditor** and everything I download there works fine. They even have a plugin that does exactly what I want (https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/exportpdf). But it's not 100% free.

My platform also allows adding custom buttons to its text editor / box. The code has to be HTML and the instructions for the code are:

> Use {option} for the value of the entered option, if applicable. Use
> {content} to indicate where the content highlighted when the button is
> pressed should be inserted. Please note that any HTML entered here
> should conform to the HTML specification (including any required
> attributes for HTML tags), otherwise the software may not process it
> correctly.

My platform is private, so pages and content are only displayed after logging in.

Is it possible to add an HTML button that converts the text in the editor box to PDF? (Even if I have to use an external website for that.)

Thanks!

Comment: @KJ hahah, I'm not sure I'm willing to spend more than a couple of hours on this. My community is super small, I don't get anything in return for keeping it. This would be just for convenience. I'm not sure I get what you mean though, lol...

Comment: @KJ hahah! I had checked that link before. I'll try to make it work when I have some free time, but I guess this whole thing is just a bit harder than I thought, not sure I'd be able to make it work by myself. Thanks for trying to help though! Once you reach $1, I'll transfer the money to you, lol